# AWS Lambda reading Athena database file and writing S3 to no avail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

A help because  are not writing the file to the S3 bucket

What did I do:

```
import time
import boto3
query = 'SELECT * FROM db_lambda.tb_inicial limit 10'
DATABASE = 'db_lambda'
output = 's3: // bucket-lambda-test1 / result /'

def lambda_handler (event, context):
    
    client = boto3.client ('athena')

    # Execution
    response = client.start_query_execution (
        QueryString = query,
        QueryExecutionContext = {
            Database: DATABASE
        },
        ResultConfiguration = {
            'OutputLocation': output,
        }
    )
    return response
    return
```

---

IAM role created with:

- AmazonS3FullAccess
- AmazonAthenaFullAccess
- CloudWatchLogsFullAccess
- AmazonVPCFullAccess
- AWSLambda_FullAccess

When running Lambda message:

```
 Response:
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "\" Hello from Lambda! \ ""
}

Request ID:
"f2dd5cd2-070c-41ea-939f-d4909ce39fd0"

Function logs:
START RequestId: f2dd5cd2-070c-41ea-939f-d4909ce39fd0 Version: $ LATEST
END RequestId: f2dd5cd2-070c-41ea-939f-d4909ce39fd0
REPORT RequestId: f2dd5cd2-070c-41ea-939f-d4909ce39fd0 Duration: 0.84 ms Billed Duration: 1 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 52 MB
```

How I did the test:

- Configure test event
- A function can have a maximum of 10 test events. The events are maintained, so that you can change your computer or web browser and test the function with the same events.
- Create new test event
- Edit saved test events
- Test event saved

```
{
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "Hello from Lambda" message is the default code in a Lambda function. It would appear that you **did not click 'Deploy'** before testing the function. Clicking **Deploy** will save the Lambda code.

Also, once you get it running, please note that `start_query_execution()` will simply start the Athena query. You will need to use `get_query_results()` to obtain the results.